# How to make a global theme object dynamic according to user input(styled components)?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, styled-components, zustand

```
<ThemeProvider theme={themes}>
  <App />
</ThemeProvider>
```

This is my global theme of styled components.

```
export const customCol = {
  primary   : "#fff",
  secondary : "#ccc",
  tertiary  : "#3c71c6",
}

export const themes = {
  bg : {
    default : {
      bg : customCol.primary
    },
  },
  button : {
   bg:customCol.secondary
  }
}
```

App.js

```
<Button>First Button</Button>
<Button>Second Button</Button>
```

I want to change the color of different components like button on user's input choice color. This should update the customCol which in turn updates the theme object bg color.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a React Context in order to dynamically change de `ThemeProvider` `theme` property.

Here is an example on how to do this, in a CRA React app, but this should be nearly the same with next.js :

https://jscircle.com/react-theme-switching-with-context-api-and-styled-components/